# Fitting distributions to data

Tags: self-study, distributions, goodness-of-fit

I have a dataset of 1000 observations of a continuous quantity, and I am trying to find a distribution that fits them best.
At first I tried the Cullen and Frey graph, with bootstraping, to get an idea.
[image]

If I read the graph correctly, it shows that the only possible candidate is the Beta distribution.
Since my observations are not in (0,1), I divided them by the maximum observation and then I tried this in R:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
fitdist(data, pbeta)
```

"data" variable has 999 elements, since I removed the last one because it was equal to 1.
Then I run both a KS and an AD goodness-of-fit tests, with the above calculated estimates, and the $p$-values I got from both were very small. In the same way I tried fitting the gamma distribution, the normal distribution, the $t$-distribution, and the chi-square distribution, but all gave very small $p$-values.

So my question is, can I conclude that none of these distributions fit my data?

Also, here is some information that might be useful: the min obseravation is 2.077023e-05, the max is 194215363660, 210 obseravations are below 10, 502 are below 1000, 813 are below 100000, 35 are above 10000000. Also the empirical density for values less than 100000, otherwise it's like a line, is [image]

Comment: A little hint about fitting data to a distribution versus fitting a distribution to the data. Data is fixed, but distributions are flexible. E.g. when fitting a normal distribution to the data you may vary the mean and the variance. Hence you fit a distribution to the data rather than the other way around.

Comment: You might have better luck trying to fit the log of your data...just a suggestion

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld, thank you very much, it worked! Since log-normal didn't seem to fit, based on the Cullen-Frey graph, I would never think to try it!